# Assign values to variables depending on another variable

Tags: c#, assign

I have a quick question to assigning values.
In my new program I am trying to assign values to booleans depending on the value of an integer. Here a quick example of what I mean:

```
bool northDoorAvailable;
int roomLocation;

// set player Location in some code
roomLocation = 2;

// now set if the north door is available
```

Is this only possible with a function in that I write alot of `if`-statements?

```
public void checkDoors() 
{
    if ( roomLocation == 1 )
    {
        northDoorAvailable = false;
    }
    if ( roomLocation == 2 )
    {
        northDoorAvailable = true;
    }
}
```

or can this process be automized?

Glad for any replies.

Comment: You could use a number of different methods, from storing the values in dictionaries to simply reducing it to a single line: `northDoorAvailable = roomLocation != 1;` for example.

Comment: Are those the only two possible conditions?  What if `roomlocation == 3`?

Comment: @RonBeyer How would I do that in a code? Sorry, I am pretty new to coding compared to you apparently :)

Comment: @DStanley No there would be others so if `roomlocation != possibleLocations` it would do `northDoorAvailable = false`

Comment: @IanH. Just like I showed you (that is a valid line of code). You can replace the entire `checkDoors` function with that, but this is assuming that `northDoorAvailable` is true only if the room location is not equal to 1. If you have other requirements, then its better to use a dictionary. I will type an answer that shows how you can use it.

Comment: @Moe like `northDoorAvailable = roomLocation == 1 ? return false : return true;`?

Comment: So what is `possibleLocations`?  If that's an array or collection, then that changes the possible syntax significantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better syntax depends greatly on all possible conditions.  Right now you could use

```
 northDoorAvailable = (roomLocation == 2);
```

or

```
 northDoorAvailable = (roomLocation != 1);
```

since `X == Y` returns `true` or `false` depending on whether or not the two are "equal". (and vice-versa for `!=`)

But what if `roomLocation` is `3`?  `4`?

In general, *usally* it is possible to simplify these conditions into a single logical expression, but it may not *always* be the case.  One way to simplify is to put all possible conditions in a ["truth table"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) and see what the equivalent logical expression is.

> there would be others so if `roomlocation != possibleLocations` it would do `northDoorAvailable = false`

I'm assuming that `possibleLocations` is a *collection* if integers, and if it *contains* `roomlocation` then `northDoorAvailable` would be `true`.  In that case you could use

```
northDoorAvailable = (possibleLocations.Contains(roomlocation));
```

Comment: @D Stanley Ahhh, now I understand. One last question: Is it possible to do this in the background while the other code is running so it doesn't have to be called over and over again?

Comment: Not like you mean, but you could make it a _property_ and do the calculation when you "get" the property.  Do some research on properties, getters, and setters, and ask another _specific_ question if you're stuck.  This is pretty basic C# stuff so you can probably find the answers out on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary for this:

```
public class MyGameClass
{
    private Dictionary<int, bool> _northDoorAvailable = new Dictionary<int, bool>();

    public MyGameClass()
    {
        _northDoorAvailable[1] = false;
        _northDoorAvailalbe[2] = true;
        _northDoorAvailable[3] = false;
        _northDoorAvailable[4] = false;
        _northDoorAvailable[5] = false;
    }

    public bool IsNorthDoorAvailable(int room)
    {
        bool available = false;
        _northDoorAvailable.TryGetValue(room, out available);
        return available;
    }
}
```

The dictionary is a key/value store where, in this case, the key is the room number, and the value (the other side of the = mark) is if the door is available or not. You can quickly add cases to the dictionary in the constructor method for whatever class you are using, and you can access the dictionary internally, or publically through the `IsNorthDoorAvailable` method.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have a sorted list and parse a word doc or db table with a list of rooms and their corresponding boolean values then just loop through the list

1 - true

2 - true

3 - false

etc...

```
SortedList<int, bool> roomsList = new SortedList<int, bool>();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\temp\RoomList.txt"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] rooms = line.Split('-');
                roomsList.Add(int.Parse(rooms[0]), bool.Parse(rooms[1]));
            }
        }
```